# App crashes when playing you tube video in webview?

Tags: android, html, webview, webkit, youtube-javascript-api

I'm new for android hybrid development. **I have embedded an Youtube video** into html page using

```
<object width="100%"  height="auto" width="auto"
type="text/html" data="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Q7DojKxaNxE">Unable to play video.
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/embed/AlSbZvK1O1Y"/>
</object>
```

and this html page is loading in webview. Now when i try to play video in webview app crashing and following is **the error log**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.webkit.HTML5VideoView.reprepareData(HTML5VideoView.java:352)
at android.webkit.HTML5VideoViewProxy$VideoPlayer.play(HTML5VideoViewProxy.java:245)
at android.webkit.HTML5VideoViewProxy.handleMessage(HTML5VideoViewProxy.java:447)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have loaded html page in webview like below,

```
this.mainWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html1/this-app.html");
```

I am tested in android 4.4.2 version samsung devices.

Please any one help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please post activity code where you used HTML5VideoView ?

Comment: Hi Haresh, actually in webview an html page is loading and in that html page i have included youtube video using object html tag.

Comment: just a suggestion, why not use the nativa YouTubePlayer https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/ ?

Comment: Hybrid framework is requirement, this html file common for android and iOS development.

Comment: @peter did this problem fixed?